# In La Liga or the Premier League, can you contest a yellow card after the game and take it off?

Tags: rules, football, english-premier-league, la-liga

As the title suggest, anyone know if a yellow card can be contested in either La Liga or the English Premier League and taken off ? If they can, are there limits as to how many can be contested?

Comment: Are you talking about *any* yellow card or a 2nd yellow card?

Comment: Any yellow card. Just in general contesting it after the match even if the referee made a mistake during the game and gave a yellow.

Answer (score 1):

At least in the Premier League, it's not possible. Back in 2000, a referee directly asked the FA to rescind a yellow card. He received no answer. This article might give a little more insight:
https://www.sports.legal/2017/12/yellow-card-suspensions-in-football-correct-me-if-im-wrong-but/